# Change number of columns for categories and products thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to change the number of columns in which are displayed the **list of categories** and the **list of products of a category**.

I’ve tried to add some filters in the `function.php` page, like below, but it makes no changes: the pages are still displaying 3 categories per row.

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 6; // 6 products per row
    }
}
```

or:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'wc_<div class="clearfix"></div>loop_shop_columns', 1, 10 );

function wc_loop_shop_columns( $number_columns ) {
    return 6; // 6 products per row
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

// 18 products per page, and 6 product per row :)

```
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', create_function('$cols', 'return 18;'), 20);
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')){
    function loop_columns(){
        return 6;
    }
}
```

Comment: and for category products?

Answer (score 0):

for products in text mode write this for products:

```
[recent_products columns="3"]
```

for categories product:

```
[product_categories columns="3"]
```

change 3 to be your customize value;